# SQL создать запрос на выборку с возможными пустыми критериями

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM Сорта WHERE Морозоустойчивость = 'Высокая' AND Урожайность = 'Средняя'
```

Нужно сделать выборку по определённым критериям, вводимых юзером. Суть в том, что критерий может быть и пустым. Например Урожайность = '', и нужно будет вывести выборку только по Морозоустойчивости.

Comment: ```SHOW CREATE TABLE Сорта;``` - в студию (откорректировать с учётом конкретной СУБД). На такой задаче точная структура таблицы критически важна. Заодно укажи СУБД и её версию - тоже немаловажно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте условие с проверкой введенных переменных в запросе на `''`. Тогда, проверка будет выполняться если их значение задано

Вместо `:morozoust` и `:urozh` у вас должны быть реальные значения. Например, переданные через биндинг, либо явно вставленные в запрос

Пример:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Сорта 
WHERE
    (:morozoust = '' OR Морозоустойчивость = :morozoust)
    AND (:urozh = '' OR Урожайность = :urozh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут надо использовать динамический запрос
Можете попробовать использовать код ниже

```py
import sqlite3

# установка соединения с базой данных
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# формирование запроса
query = "SELECT * FROM Сорта WHERE 1=1 "
params = []

morozoust = input("Введите морозоустойчивость (Высокая/Средняя/Низкая): ")
if morozoust != "":
    query += "AND Морозоустойчивость = ? "
    params.append(morozoust)

urozh = input("Введите урожайность (Высокая/Средняя/Низкая): ")
if urozh != "":
    query += "AND Урожайность = ? "
    params.append(urozh)

# выполнение запроса
result = cursor.execute(query, params).fetchall()

# вывод результатов
for row in result:
    print(row)

# закрытие соединения с базой данных
conn.close()
```